# Окно в 3D играх на Unity3D 5

Tags: unity3d

Подскажите с помощью чего создать окошки 3D играх. Лучше будет с помощью 3D объектов например plane или UI-интерфейса Canvas

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под окошками?

Comment: ессли интерфейсные то однозначно лучше через UI он под это заточен